# What mechanism is behind whether large enemies flinch or not?

Tags: guacamelee

Large enemies such as Hammertimes, Lightnings, and bosses seem to have no real pattern behind whether they flinch or not when hit by a normal attack. Is there a hidden mechanic behind it, or is it actually random?